# Can noweb create traversable links in latex like it does in HTML?

Tags: literate-programming, noweb

When you generate html documents with noweb each chunk of code can be clicked when referenced elsewhere and you can jump to this definition but I'm not able to get the same functionality with the generated Latex document.

Can the generated latex documents have clickable links between different chunks of code?

Comment: use the hyperref package via `\usepackage{hyperref}`.

Comment: @DanD.: Please post your answer as an **Answer** so we can up vote it properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the hyperref package via `\usepackage{hyperref}`.

you might want to configure the package further. for that i refer you to the search [hyperref](http://www.google.com/search?q=hyperref).